# Why ReactJS Dockerfile has two COPY commands?

Tags: reactjs, dockerfile

In most of Dockerfile for ReactJS application, I see that two COPY instructions. One is to copy package.json and after installing node_modules, another COPY instruction to copy source code.

Ex:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Can't we do with just one COPY command? Any advantage of using two COPy commands?

Also, for ReactJS deployment, `npm start` method is preferred or deploying to `nginx` is preferred?

Answer (score 1):

To keep build times to a minimum, Docker caches the results of executing a line in the Dockerfile for use in a future build. With NPM we only want to re-run npm install if something within our package.json file has changed. If nothing has changed then we can use the cache version to speed up deployment. By using COPY package.json  we can cause the RUN npm install command to be invalidated if the package.json file has changed.

Comment: Thank you @tmohammad78. But isn't it same if we copy entire files. Should we specify single file to check if the file is changed or not.